# Register Page in ASP.NET in C# within MS Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggling to make my register page work in asp.net in C#. I keep on getting errors when I run my code.
I created a button with a click event.

```
protected void btn_Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection Regconn = new SqlConnection(
            // when logging in, use the following
                //"Data Source=LAPTOP-MHFEI4S3;Initial Catalog=db_OnlineBookClub; User ID=sa; Password=p@55word;");
            // with windows authentication use the following
                "Data Source=LAPTOP-MHFEI4S3;Initial Catalog=db_OnlineBookClub;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        //opening database connection                
        Regconn.Open();

        //creating CRUD statement
        SqlCommand cmdReg = Regconn.CreateCommand();
        cmdReg.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tbl_userInfo (name, surname, age, email, pword, securityQuestion, securityAnswer) 
                            VALUES('" + txt_Name.Text + "', '" + txt_Surname.Text + "', '" + 
                                txt_Age.Text + "', '" + txt_Email.Text + "', '" + txt_Password.Text + "', '" + 
                                txt_Q.Text + "', '" + txt_A.Text + "')";

        cmdReg.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //closing database connection
        Regconn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }

    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl_RegError.Text = err.Message;
    }
}
```

Apparently, there is an error within my insert CRUD statement.

Comment: [SQL Injection warning](https://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: It's possible that one of the values is null or empty in which case the value should set be set to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: where should I type the DBNull.Value ?

Comment: In the connection string, if userid and password are specified, the values both need to be surrounded by single-quotes.

Comment: @user9938: this should never be required, plain values of username and password should be fine in a connection string

Answer (score 1):

Please use parameters to prevent SQL injection. If a value is null, the value for the parameter needs to be set to `DBNull.Value`.  Use `using` statements which ensure that the connections are properly closed. Also close the connection after each operation.

Try the following:

Add the following using statements:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**Register**:

```
private void Register(string name, string surname, string age, string email, string encryptedPwd, string securityQuestion, string encryptedSecurityAnswer, string connectionStr)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO tbl_userInfo(name, surname, age, email, pword, securityQuestion, securityAnswer) VALUES(@name, @surname, @age, @email, @pword, @securityQuestion, @securityAnswer);";


    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            //open connection
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con))
            {
                //name
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //surname
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = surname;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //age
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = age;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //email
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //pword
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedPwd))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = encryptedPwd;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //securityQuestion
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(securityQuestion))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@securityQuestion", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = securityQuestion;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@securityQuestion", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //securityAnswer
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedSecurityAnswer))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = encryptedSecurityAnswer;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@securityAnswer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

                //execute; returns the number of rows affected
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        lbl_RegError.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;

        //uncomment the following for debugging
        //throw ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_RegError.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;

        //uncomment the following for debugging
        //throw ex;
    }
}
```

See [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) for more info about connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use this approach.
The text boxes when empty are NOT null, so there really no need to write code to check them all.

```
string strCon = "Data Source = LAPTOP - MHFEI4S3; Initial Catalog = db_OnlineBookClub; Integrated Security = SSPI; ";

string strSQL = "INSERT INTO People " +
                "(name, surname, age, email, pword, securityQuestion, securityAnswer) " +
                "VALUES (@tName, @surname, @age, @email, @pword, @Q, @A)";

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,new SqlConnection(strCon)))

    {
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@tName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Name.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Surname.Text;
    
    if (txtAge.Text == "") { txtAge.Text = "0"; }
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_Age.Text;

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Email.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@pword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Password.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Q", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Q.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@A", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_A.Text;

    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    }
```

You note in above:

```
Strong data types - no need for messy string concatenations
No sql injection issues.
Strong casting of types - automatic for you. 
Easy to read - easy to add MORE values, or remove them
Used ctrl-d in editor to repeat the first line - so I actually typed LESS code.
Using block cleans up - closes connection for you.
No need to create a connection object - sqlcommand has one
No need to create or set command text - sqlcommand has one.
And, sqlcommand also has a reader - so if needed, you don't create either.
```